# ImportError: No module named FlaskApp

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I am puzzled by no module named app importerror. When I use name FlaskApp, everything works, when I change name to xyzApp, it does not and I am getting ImportError.

Here is the error code:

```
Target WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/xyzApp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/xyzApp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/xyz/xyzApp.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
from xyzApp import app as application
ImportError: No module named 'xyzApp'
Target WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/xyzApp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/xyz/xyzApp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/xyz/xyzApp.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
from xyzApp import app as application
ImportError: No module named 'xyzApp'
```

The Structure of the Flask applications looks as follows:

```
/var/www/xyz/
        |--xyzApp.wsgi
        |--/instance/config.py
        |--/xyzApp
                  |--/static
                  |--/templates
                  |--__init__.py
```

When I do application with similar structure but with FlaskApp folders, it works. Why is that?
The structure that works is as follows:

```
/var/www/FlaskApp/
        |--flaskapp.wsgi
        |--/FlaskApp
                  |--/static
                  |--/templates
                  |--__init__.py
```

The content of flaskapp.wsgi file is the same except for xyzApp:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

 import sys
 import logging
 logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
 sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp")

 from FlaskApp import app as application
```

Comment: show `.wsgi` which makes problem. Maybe you forgot something in this file.

Comment: I have shown it - the last grey-colored block.

Comment: the xyzApp.wsgi has all the same except last line is: from xyzApp import app as application

Comment: no, you show `flaskapp.wsgi` but not `xyzApp.wsgi`

Comment: did you change `/var/www/FlaskApp` ?

Comment: yes, I did: sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/xyzApp/")

Comment: I have shown both flaskapp.wsgi and xyzApp.wsgi

Comment: but your structure shows you have folder `/var/www/xyz/`, not `/var/www/xyzAPP/`

Comment: I see - thank you. I will try.

Comment: Thanks - I corrected the error and it solved the issue.